# How do I add a bookmark within the body of a Word doc using interop

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, interop

I have a template document which contains a number of bookmarks used thus;
mDoc.Bookmarks(bookmark).Range.Text = "My test".

I would now like to add a new bookmark at the position in the doc at the end of the string "My test" but cannot find any guidance on how to specify the range in;

```
 Dim Bookmarks As Word.Bookmarks
        Dim myBookmark As Word.Bookmark
        Dim bookmarkRange As Word.Range
        Dim Selection As Word.Selection


        'doc = mWord.ActiveDocument
        Selection = mWord.Selection
        bookmarkRange = Selection.Range
        Bookmarks = mDoc.Bookmarks
        myBookmark = Bookmarks.Add("MyBookmark", bookmarkRange)   'this works but puts it at the start of the doc
        mDoc.Bookmarks("MyBookmark").Range.Text = "text inserted at MyBookmark"
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code does not add text to the bookmarked range; it inserts that text *after* the bookmark. To add text to a bookmarked range, use something like the following VBA code:

```
Dim BkMkRng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  If .Bookmarks.Exists("MyBookmark") Then
    Set BkMkRng = .Bookmarks("MyBookmark").Range
    BkMkRng.Text = "My Text"
    .Bookmarks.Add "MyBookmark", BkMkRng
  End If
End With
```

To insert an new bookmark after that range, simply use something along the lines of:

```
With ActiveDocument
  If .Bookmarks.Exists("MyBookmark") Then
    Set BkMkRng = .Bookmarks("MyBookmark").Range
    BkMkRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    BkMkRng.Text = "My New Text"
    .Bookmarks.Add "MyNewBookmark", BkMkRng
  End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

From where you are, you could replace

```
mDoc.Bookmarks("MyBookmark").Range.Text = "text inserted at MyBookmark"
```

with

```
    Dim myRange As Word.Range
    myRange = mDoc.Bookmarks(myBookmark).Range
    myRange.Text = "text inserted at MyBookmark"
    myRange.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
    myRange.Bookmarks.Add("MyNewBookmark")
```